# Regarding Python and Kivy, why can't I add widgets?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

this is my first time using Stack Overflow, and my English is terrible.
I apologize in advance for any inconvenience.
I would like to know why I am unable to add widgets.
I am attempting to write a large app, so I plan to divide different screens into files and control them from a main file. However, when I run the program, there are no errors, but the screen remains unchanged.

main.py

```
from LifeScreen import LifeScreen
import SetScreen
import DataScreen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.window import Window


Builder.load_string('''
<ScreenManager>:    
    LifeScreen:    
    SetScreen:
    DataScreen:
''')


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TestApp(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        LabelBase.register(name='Roboto', fn_regular='kaiu.ttf')
        LabelBase.register(name='RobotoMedium', fn_regular='kaiu.ttf')
        Config.set("kivy", "default_font", ['Roboto', 'kaiu.ttf', 'Times.ttf'])

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"

    def build(self):
        Window.size = (9*35, 20*35)
        life_screen = LifeScreen()
        life_screen.new_ScrollViewList_button("大限列表", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
        return ScreenManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    TestApp().run()
```

LifeScreen.py

```
import os
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.effects.fadingedge.fadingedge import FadingEdgeEffect
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "LifeScreen.kv"), encoding="utf-8") as kv_file:
    Builder.load_string(kv_file.read())


class FadeScrollView(FadingEdgeEffect, ScrollView):
    pass


class LifeScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LifeScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def new_ScrollViewList_button(self, id, data):
        for i in data:
            print(f"self.ids:{self.ids}")
            self.ids[id].add_widget(
                MDRectangleFlatButton(text=f"Single-line item {i}", id="{i}")
            )
```

I hope to be able to control other screens (LifeScreen, SetScreen, DataScreen) in main.py, so that the application does not become too large and messy. Perhaps I can use them like official widgets. However, my programming skills are poor, and I don't understand where the problem lies. There are no error messages in the program, but I am unable to use the `new_ScrollViewList_button` defined in LifeScreen.py in main.py, in order to add a new button in LifeScreen.kv.

No matter whether you can help or not, thank you for being willing to open and read this. Thank you, stranger.